# Inverse trigonometric problem (cutting down calculations)

Tags: trigonometry

Okay what if something like this pops up?$sin^{-1}(1-x)-2sin^{-1}x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. How would you solve this?

I tried to convert into $tan^{-1}$ but it just got too lengthy. Any ideas how you would do it would be wonderful. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Because $\sin(0) = 0$ and $\sin(\pi/2) = 1$, you have $x=0$ is a solution. Solving it "algebraically" seems hard, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $\theta = \sin^{-1} x$, then we see
\begin{align}
\sin^{-1}(1-\sin\theta) = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\theta \ \ \Rightarrow&\  \ \ 1-\sin\theta = \sin\left( \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\theta\right) = \cos(2\theta) = 1-2\sin^2(\theta)\\
\Rightarrow&\ \sin\theta(1-2\sin\theta) = 0.
\end{align}
Then it follows either $\sin\theta = 0$ or $\sin\theta = \frac{1}{2}$. In the first case, we have
\begin{align}
 \sin(\sin^{-1} x) = 0 \ \ \Rightarrow  \  x=0.
\end{align}
In the second case, we have
\begin{align}
\sin(\sin^{-1} x) = \frac{1}{2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
but $x=\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't satisfy the above equation. Thus $x=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: Awesome! I'm up voting. Can you consider up voting this post too?

Answer (score 0):

We have $\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin^{-1}(1-x)=-2\sin^{-1}x,\;\;$ so $\cos^{-1}(1-x)=-2\sin^{-1}x$.

Therefore $0\le -2\sin^{-1} x\le\pi$, so $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le\sin^{-1}x\le0$ and  $-1\le x\le0$.

Since $\cos(\cos^{-1}(1-x))=\cos(-2\sin^{-1}x)=\cos(2\sin^{-1}x)=\cos^2(\sin^{-1}x)-\sin^2(\sin^{-1}x),$

$\;\;\;1-x=(1-x^2)-x^2=1-2 x^2\implies 2x^2-x=0\implies x(2x-1)=0\implies x=0$

$\;\;\;$(since $-1\le x\le 0$)